# Linking time dimension with fact table

Tags: olap, cube, olap-cube

I'm trying to add a time dimension in BIDS 2008, creating it does fine, but I can't seem to link it to my fact table.

The fact table has a field name openDate which is a DATE field (not NULL), in the dimension usage tab I add it and define a regular date relation with the openDate field.

Deploying fails with a load of errors, removing it solves all the issues. I've been at this for a few hours now, save me, please :)

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone: the problem source was that the column in the fact table was date, what had to be changed was in the ETL, a conversion from date to date time stamp had to be added.